# Django - accessing related objects in a template

Tags: django, django-templates

How can I access a related object in a django template?
I simply want to display the post title of the the bookmark at my template.
Assuming the following view and model(s):

```
def my_bookmarks(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        list_my_bookmarks = sorted(
            chain(
                UserBookmarks.objects.filter(user=request.user),
            ), key=attrgetter('date_added'), reverse=True
        )
        paginator = Paginator(list_my_bookmarks, 20)  # Show 20 bookmarks per page
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        my_bookmarks = paginator.get_page(page)
        user = request.user
        args = {'user': user,
                'my_bookmarks': my_bookmarks,
                }
        return render(request, 'App/my_bookmarks.html', args)


bookmarkable_post_models = models.Q(app_label='App', model='post') | models.Q(app_label='App', model='model-b') | models.Q(app_label='App', model='model-c')


class UserBookmarks(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=False, blank=False)
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, limit_choices_to=bookmarkable_post_models, related_name='bookmarks', related_query_name='bookmark', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=False)
    object_id = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False)
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=False)


class Post(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(verbose_name="Post Title", max_length=20)
    content = models.TextField(verbose_name="Content of Post")
    ...
    bookmarks = GenericRelation(UserBookmarks, related_query_name='post')
```

Accessing the bookmark objects itself does not seem to be a problem if I do: 
{{ my_bookmarks }} at my template but i dont understand how to access the post element behind the bookmark

Thanks for reading

Comment: `bookmark.post`?

Comment: Nope, thats not working.

Comment: `bookmark.content_object`?

Comment: Again nothing which makes sense as im accessing UserBookmarks not Post. I dont know if "bookmark" makes even sense at that point as i want to get the Post object behind the UserBookmarks object...

Comment: Or do I maybe have to go the other way around so that I'm accessing Post.bookmarks at my view.py?

Comment: `content_object` should work. Are you sure the generic key columns have the correct data?

Comment: my_bookmarks.content_object.title is working fine, thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

- `mybookmarks.post` is a `RelationManager`,
- `mybookmarks.post.all()` is a `Queryset`.

You can iterate over in template :

````py
{% for post in mybookmarks.post.all %}
    {{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```
````

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the _set to get the related `Post` objects?

for example:

```
{% for post in my_bookmarks.post_set.all() %}
   {{ post.title }}
{% endfor %}
```

This will print the title of every `Post` related to your `UserBookmark`.

Answer (score 0):

The following has worked for me:

```
 {% for bookmark in my_bookmarks %}
    <p>{{ bookmark.content_object.title }}</p>
```

Please also see comment section of my question.

Thanks everybody